# Why do I have to force a downcast of an array object to a subclass in swift

Tags: swift

I have the following -- simplified -- code:

```
class A {
    var x: Int = 9

}

class B: A {
    var y: Int = 8
}


class S {
    var myList = [A]()
}


//class T: S {
//    override var myList = [B]()
//}

class V: S {

    func foo() {
        let bar = myList[2] as! B
        print(bar.y)
    }
}
```

In swift 2.1 I have to use the as! or I get the error message that A is not convertible to B.  It seems wrong that I should have to force a conversion to the subclass, but maybe I'm missing something.

The commented out part was my first attempt, but that does not compile either with the message myList with type '[B]' cannot override a property with type '[A]'

In both cases I don't understand the behavior since B is clearly a subclass of A.

1. Can someone explain why I cannot override the declaration?
2. Can someone explain why I have to force the downcast?

Thanks!

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to know that `myList` contains `B`?

Comment: In almost any language you have to explicitly downcast (cast to subclass). The same is true in Java or C++.

Comment: I understand that you have to explicitly downcast, that wasn't my question.  My question was why I had to add the ! to force the downcast.

Answer (score 0):

For point (1), you cannot override stored properties at all, only computed properties. Moreover, even when you override a computed property, you can't give it a different type, as you attempt to do here. And since you can't change the type, it actually makes no sense to override a stored property - what would you override it *to*? If it was an `int` in the superclass and an `int` in the subclass, or an `[A]` in the the superclass and an `[A]` in the subclass, then you haven't actually changed anything by overriding it. You can change behavior by overriding a computed property, but obviously not with a stored property, so it makes little sense to do so.

For point (2), you have to force the downcast because you are attempting to access a property - namely, `y` - that isn't present in the superclass. If you want to access a subclass through a superclass reference, you have to restrict yourself to the interface provided by that superclass. `A` doesn't have a `y` property, so trying to access `bar.y` when `bar` is of type `A` makes no sense - you have to downcast it to type `B` to do that.

In OOP generally, converting upwards is usually easy, since we know from the inheritance structure that `B` is an `A`, so converting it that way is simple. But the same is not true in the opposite direction - when `B` inherits from `A`, then a `B` is an `A`, but an `A` is not a `B`. Therefore, when you convert downwards from `A` to `B`, you have to do so explicitly, because bad things can happen if the thing you are converting turns out not to be a `B` at all.

Incidentally, you don't have to *force* the downcast with `as!` - you can safely attempt it with `as?`, for instance:

```
if let bar = mylist[2] as? B {
    print(bar.y)
}
else {
    print("not a B!")
}
```

Comment: The error was not on accessing y the error was on the line `let bar = myList[2] as B`  The compiler makes me at the ! to the as, which seemed a little excessive as B is a subclass of A.  And myList was declared to be an array of A's.